# Why does the setTimeout callback wait for the end of the loop when the timer is 0ms?

Tags: javascript

The thing I don't understand about closures is the fact that the `setTimeout` callbacks don't fire until the loop has finished. It looks to me that clearly the function is being executed during each iteration.

I am not concerned why they are all "6"'s I understand that part. I just need an explanation as to why it waits till the loop has to finish before they actually run.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
{
    setTimeout(function timer() 
    {
        console.log(i);
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: The most common javascript duplicate.

Comment: It's because JavaScript is single threaded, so the current synchronous execution of code (the loop) must finish before any asynchronous code (the `setTimeout` callbacks)` can execute.

Comment: ...additionally, passing `0` to `setTimeout` never really means `0` milliseconds. There's typically a minimum established.

Comment: @djechlin: How closely did you read the question?

Comment: @cookiemonster not very. it's the 2nd most common javascript question ("why doesn't my async code run immediately")

Comment: @djechlin: Well I've got to admit that it's set up to sound like the typical "functions in a loop" problem. I don't know how common this one is, but at least it's a little more interesting than the norm. But yeah, I'd imagine there are plenty of dupes out there.

Comment: @mike: Just so you understand, the fact that the callbacks don't fire until after the loop has nothing to do with closures. That's an entirely different concept. But WRT the minimum timer value, it ultimately won't make a difference. If you test your code in NodeJS using `.nextTick()`, you'll get the same delayed behavior.

Comment: @cookiemonster 1. Is it waiting for my for loop to finish or is it just a timing issue? 2.  Is my FOR loop part of the event loop?

Comment: @mike628: 1) Both, but either of them alone would cause the same thing. 2) If this code is just part of the initial program loading, I wouldn't think of it as such, but others describe it that way, so perhaps technically it is. But the event loop is just a mechanism for handling asynchronous events of various description. The important thing to realize is that synchronous code blocks any other code from running because the JS environment is single threaded.

Comment: ...imagine if you did `setTimeout(function() { alert("foo"); }, 25);`. You'd expect the callback to be invoked after roughly `25ms`. But now imagine that the very next line of code after the `setTimeout` call runs a loop that blocks for `2000ms`. You won't see your `alert()` until after the `2000ms` has expired because the loop blocked it for that time. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94zny/2/) that illustrates it.

Answer (score 3):

The setTimeouts are queued to start running at the end of the current event loop.  So, the setTimeouts can fire much later than the end of the for loop.

MDN has a great description about the event loop with regard to setTimeout:

```
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop
```

Specifically this part:

> Calling setTimeout will add a message to the queue after the time
>   passed as second argument. If there is no other message in the queue,
>   the message is processed right away; however, if there are messages,
>   the setTimeout message will have to wait for other messages to be
>   processed. For that reason the second argument indicates a minimum
>   time and not a guaranteed time.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs with a single [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop).

The event loop is busy running the function that is calling `setTimeout` so it isn't looking to see if any events are on the timeout queue waiting to run.

Even if that wasn't the case, most JS implementations implement a minimum timeout (see [Minimum delay and timeout nesting](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html)) value and raise whatever you pass (`0`) to it if it falls below that value.